# Updating Anaconda: Python crasses

Tags: python, spyder

I have just updated anaconda using the following code in command prompt:

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
```

The problem is that now when I click to spyder.exe I got the following error message:

[image]

It seems that this is happening when `loading editor` is showed in the spyder loading icon(sometimes also in `loading history plugin`). Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried to update spyder app too?

Comment: In the documentation it is written that when you update anaconda also spyder is updated. source: https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/installation.html